# @Pattern annotation used as a part of bean validation in spring mvc, is repeatedly throwing the same error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, annotations

I used @pattern annotation to validate the input for studentName. If I submit the invalid input once, its showing the error message as expected. But if I reload the page and submit the valid input, its showing the same error message again. Is there a way to clear the previous binding errors

I have tried restarting the server

Student bean class :

import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public class Student {

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*")
private String studentName;


public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}
```

}

Controller class :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitAdmissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student1") Student student, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
            return model;
        }
        ModelAndView model2 = new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
        return model2;
    }
```

studentMessages.properties :

Pattern.student1.studentName = custom error message.

spring-dispatcher-servlet :

```
<bean id = "messageSource" class = "org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name = "basename" value = "/WEB-INF/studentMessages"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with clearing errors. It's just that your input is still invalid based on your regex. Test and fix the regex. Currently, a student name is valid only if it contains only numbers. I doubt that's what you want. Tip: whether you're a newbie or an expert, if there is a bug, there is a much higher chance that the bug comes from your code than from a battle-tested framework.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the case. But the thing here is even if I give a valid input (after giving the invalid input on the first go), I still see the same error. Hope you got what I am trying to say.